# Instantiate operators on enum types only on certain enums

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a bitflag style class like the following

```
template <typename EnumT>
struct Flags 
{
    using UType = std::underlying_type_t<EnumT>;
    static_assert(std::is_enum_v<EnumT>, "Flags must use an enum type");
    Flags() =default;
    Flags(EnumT e) : m_value{e}{}


    EnumT m_value {0};
}
```

which I want to use like this

```
enum class Enum
{
    One = 1 << 1,
    Two = 1 << 2,
};

int main()
{
    Flags a = Enum::One | Enum::Two;
}
```

To do that I need to add the `operator|` for the `Enum` type, and since `Flags` can be of any kind of `Enum`, I need to create a template

```
template <typename EnumT>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<EnumT>, EnumT> operator|(EnumT lhs, EnumT rhs) noexcept
{
    using UType = std::underlying_type_t<EnumT>;
    return static_cast<EnumT>(static_cast<UType>(lhs) | static_cast<UType>(rhs));
}
```

This works fine, but the issue I see is that its going to create the template for any Enum type in the project, and I would like to somehow restrict the operators to only the Enums used in the Flags.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to restrict it to certain enum *types* or certain enum *values* of a specific enum?

Comment: Certain enum types. I would be okay having a list, of specifying prior to use the Flags some trait on the enum

Comment: So you want something like `is_flag_enum` trait and use that to restrict instantiation in both the declaration of `Flag` and the operators?

Comment: Yeah. Actually, while I was writing the answer to your question, I realised that would suffice and I have draft it https://godbolt.org/z/eWoozs5zo